# Set Sqldatasource parameter dynamically

Tags: c#, parameters, sqldatasource

I have create a `gridview` and a `SqlDataSource`, which has parameter in the where clause, which has a source in a dropdown menu. That works fine.

I also have an input textfield. I would like the value from it to set the parameter in the same `SqlDataSource`, when an `onclick` event occurs, and then refreshing the `gridview`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as shown below you add it as a parameter to the sql data source:-

```
<SelectParameters>
   //...existing paramaters
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="SprocArgName" ControlID="txtBoxName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Just treat an empty string as no filter in your sql. Otherwise you will have to add a checkbox to say you want to use the text box filter, you can then add a second controlparamater to the sqldatasource and check for that bool value.

Comment: How can I do it in C# through an onlick event?